# How to view the implementation of python's built-in functions in pycharm?

Tags: python, function, pycharm, built-in

When I try to view the built-in function all() in PyCharm, I could just see "pass" in the function body. How to view the actual implementation so that I could know what exactly the built-in function is doing?

```
def all(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """
    Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.

    If the iterable is empty, return True.
    """
    pass
```

Comment: Seen that it's a built-in function, it most likely is written in C, thous the name "built-in" ... is directly built in the interpreter. (just my 2 cents)

Comment: Do you have an interpreter properly selected? It works for me when I right-click on `all()` and then select `Go To` / `Declaration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you’re using the usual CPython interpreter, `all` is a builtin function object, which just has a pointer to a compiled function statically linked into the interpreter (or libpython). Showing you the x86_64 machine code at that address probably wouldn’t be very useful to the vast majority of people.

---

Try running your code in PyPy instead of CPython. Many things that are builtins in CPython are plain old Python code in PyPy.<sup>1</sup> Of course that isn’t always an option (e.g., PyPy doesn’t support 3.7 features yet, there are a few third-party extension modules that are still way too slow to use, it’s harder to build yourself if you’re on some uncommon platform…), so let’s go back to CPython.

---

The actual C source for that function isn’t too hard to find online. It’s in [`bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/bltinmodule.c). But, unlike the source code to the Python modules in your standard library, you probably don’t have these files around. Even if you *do* have them, the only way to connect the binary to the source is through debugging output emitted when you compiled CPython from that source, which you probably didn’t do. But if you’re thinking that sounds like a great idea—it is. Build CPython yourself (you may want a `Py_DEBUG` build), and then you can just run it in your C source debugger/IDE and it can handle all the clumsy bits.

But if that sounds more scary than helpful, even though you can read basic C code and would like to find it…

---

How did I know where to find that code on GitHub? Well, I know where the repo is; I know the basic organization of the source into Python, Objects, Modules, etc.; I know how module names usually map to C source file names; I know that builtins is special in a few ways…

That’s all pretty simple stuff. Couldn’t you just program all that knowledge into a script, which you could then build a PyCharm plugin out of?

You can do the first 50% or so in a quick evening hack, and such things litter the shores of GitHub. But actually doing it right requires handling a ton of special cases, parsing some ugly C code, etc. And for anyone capable of writing such a thing, it’s easier to just lldb Python than to write it.

---

<sub>1. Also, even the things that *are* builtins are written in a mix of Python and a Python subset called RPython, which you might find easier to understand than C—then again, it’s often even harder to find that source, and the multiple levels that all look like Python can be hard to keep straight.</sub>

Comment: thanks for answering, I am a programming newbie and just understand a part of your answer, what do you mean by __connect the binary to the source__?   I guess  I am asking the navigation from python function to source code in  C, there are not binary right?

Comment: @LukAron the Windows compiled C is an .exe or .bin file  which is a binary file (machine language code). I think connecting the binary to the source here means relating the abstract function declaration you see in the python code to its implementation in the binary file.

Comment: @abarnert This is an awesome answer! Thanks. It solves the puzzle that I've had for years. Great day ahead!