# How to Debug Built-in functions of Python in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am using PyCharm as my IDE. Now when I write a script in python as shown below I can place **Breakpoints** throughout the code and can take any **Debugging Actions** i.e Step Into, Step Out, etc.

Why can't I Step Into any built-in function e.g as in my script below max()?

And when I go to implementation of built-in function, the function implementaion contains only *pass*. I searched Stackoverflow found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081316/how-to-view-the-implementation-of-pythons-built-in-functions-in-pycharm).

```
 a = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]

    
def max_element(values):
    """
    Finds the max element in an iterable.
    """
    result = -float('inf')
    for value in values:
        if value > result:
            result = value
    return result


max_element_from_builtin = max(a)
print(max_element_from_builtin)

max_element_from_custom = max_element(a)
print(max_element_from_custom)
```

So, how to see implementation and debug the built-in functions of Python in PyCharm?

Comment: Built-in functions can be C implemened. Depending on the debugger and the build settings you can not step into them. It shouldn't be nessesary to debug your code anyway.

Comment: @KlausD. Script is for clarifying my question.